# How to distinguish between nonlinear and linear

Tags: linear-transformations, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I ve two questions.

**First** . How to distinguish between nonlinear and linear

The difference between linear and nonlinear as I know is whether it is proportional to the result or not.

(that is linear is Linear equation  )

**second .**
 Is it nonlinear to use an index as a variable in a MIP model?

for example)

$$sp_i \cdot y_{i,f} \le c_{f,t}\quad\forall i,j\quad\text{and}\quad t=S_i,\cdots,C_i.$$

$$S_i,C_i  \ :  variables , t: index .$$

If so, can you tell why?

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear form in the variables $x_i$ is $\sum a_i x_i$ where $a_i$ are arbitrary constants. If you have products or powers of $x_i$ it is non-linear.

Some non-linear functions, like $|a_i x_i + b_i|$, for example, you can express in linear form using tricks.

Index in a MIP does not necessarily make it nonlinear. For example, the sum 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^5 kx_k = x_1 + 2x_2 + \ldots 5x_5
$$ 
is a valid linear combination of the variables, and so is the constraint
$$
\sum_{k=1}^5 kx_k \le \sum_{i=3}^6 iy_i + \sum_{i=1}^{10}i^2,
$$
since $\sum_{i=1}^{10}i^2$ is constant in the variables $x_i,y_i$ (but non-linear in $i$, which does not matter for the problem since we are only concerned with linearity in variables).
But $\sum x_k^k$ would be nonlinear when $k \not \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for you!